# Sending Thunderbird email after checking with extension

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to write a restartless Thunderbird addon to check the addresses on an email before sending it. I think I have that. But it seems that the command to send the mail, if it passes, is no longer working. In the overlay extension I had 
SendMessage.apply(this,arguments);

Does anyone know how to do this?

All I really have at the moment is the code from the overlay style extension that I'm trying to replace with a restartless one.

```
if (!SingleDomainSendMessage) { 
    SingleDomainSendMessage = SendMessage; 
    SendMessage = function() 
    { 
        if (!SingleDomain.check()) { return; } 
        SingleDomainSendMessage.apply(this, arguments); 
    }; 
}
```

This code is run when a message is sent and if it passes the test in `SingleDomain.check` the email is sent.

Comment: important pieces of code you already have will be helpful

Comment: no-one can really help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: All I really have at the moment is the code from the overlay style extension that I'm trying to replace with a restartless one. 
`code`if (!SingleDomainSendMessage) {
 SingleDomainSendMessage = SendMessage;
 SendMessage = function() {
  if (!SingleDomain.check()) {
   return;
  }
  SingleDomainSendMessage.apply(this, arguments);
 };
}`code` This code is run when a message is sent and if it passes the test in SingleDomain.check the email is sent.

Comment: Use the edit button below your question to include extra details. This is better than adding it as a comment.